# Ho to write Select query for EAV - Entity Attribute Value model

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, entity-attribute-value

I have following schema. In which

- `Types` represent DB Table
- `TypeProperty` represents Column of Table
- `TypeRow` represent Row of table

I want to write a select query to which I will pass single `Type` and it should give me all its `TypeProperty`, `TypeRow` and `TypeValue` that are associated with these *Properties* and *Rows*.

I will be showing this data in a web application in which user will select a *Type* from dropdown and application will get *Properties*, *Rows* and associated *values* and will show them as a complete grid.

**I am using SQL Server 2014.**

Can anyone help me please?

[image]

Comment: BTW one of the reasons the EAV is a bad pattern is that it's tricky to get the table structure correct to maximize the (terrible) performance.  You should be using compound keys for TypeValue of (TypeRowId, TypePropertyId) instead of having a single-column artificial key.

Comment: EAV is not evil.  I understand we all have dogmas, but in my opinion, It is just another option in your toolbelt. Under the right circumstances, it can be a valuable and effective solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, i'm going to try and take a crack at what you have been getting help with Kannan on.
It sounds like you have two different queries to the database:
    1) Query results of the list of 'Type(s)' for your dropdown,(You should be able to do this fairly easily)
    2) query results of the list of 'Propert(ies)', 'Row(s)', and 'value(s) that match the selected 'Type' in the dropdown  as a table with the properties as the header to set table.

To me it seems the easest and best way to handle this would be to get the data back using Kannan's script (probably inside of a stored procedure and maybe a view?)  and create the grid in code from your back-end application, or front end client. However, if you cant, here is a script that should work or at the least get you started.

I would suggest maybe creating two stored procs, one to retrieve the data, and another to pivot using dynamic sql.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.EAV_GridGenerator 
    @TypeId int = 0,
    @param2 int  
AS
BEGIN TRY
DECLARE @cols varchar(max),
        @query varchar(max);
        --TODO: CLEAN UP VARIABLE NAMES THROUGHOUT
SELECT trow.TypesId, tprop.PropertyName AS [Column], trow.TypeRowId AS [RowID], tval.Value AS [Data]
INTO #TT2
FROM dbo.[Types] AS t
    JOIN dbo.TypeRow trow
        ON t.typesId = trow.typesId
        JOIN dbo.TypeValue tval
            ON tval.TypeRowsId = trow.TypeRowId
            JOIN dbo.[TypeProperty] tprop
                ON tval.TypesPropertyId = tprop.TypePropertyId
WHERE trow.TypesId = @TypeId
    --AND  t.IsActive = 1   AND  tprop.IsActive = 1 AND  trow.IsActive = 1  AND  tval.IsActive = 1--TODO: IDK but you should probably add both of these
--      AND t.IsDelete = 1  AND  tprop.IsDelete = 1 AND  trow.IsDelete = 1  AND  tval.IsDelete = 1--TODO: IDK but you should probably add both of these
ORDER BY RowID, [Column], Data


SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT 
                                '],[' + t.[Column] 
                        FROM    #TT2 AS t 
                        --ORDER BY '],[' + t.ID 
                        FOR XML PATH('') 
                      ), 1, 2, '') + ']' 

SET @query = N'SELECT RowID,'+ @cols +' FROM 
(SELECT tt2.RowID,tt2.[Column] , tt2.Data FROM #tt2 AS tt2) p 
PIVOT (max([data]) FOR [Column] IN ( '+ @cols +')) 
AS pvt;' 

EXECUTE(@query)

drop table #TT2 

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    --TODO: PROPER CATCH
END CATCH
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks! Man.

Answer (score 1):

A simple join will work.. Are you looking this?

```
Select * --your required columns
   from Types t
   inner join TypesProperty tp
       on t.TypesId = tp.TypesId
   inner join TypeRow tr
       on t.TypesId = tr.TypesId
   Left join TypeValue tv
       on tp.TypesPropertyId = tv.TypesPrpertyId
```

--You need to join using typeRowid with typeValue if your require value details

Comment: Thanks @Kannan for your reply. This is the result of query provided by you.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/t1eg8k3zzuh0as2/00001_EAV.png?dl=0

But its hard for me to show this data in Grid. Can this query be refined little bit more ? So I get Grid like structure ? I have tried `Piviot` but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Can you provide me your required result format/expected output?

Comment: I want this type of grids in my Web Application. 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tp0l7te6xvw3981/00002_EAV.png?dl=0

User will select `TypeName` from which may be `Department` or `Employee` for example. Once the `TypeName` is selected I application will populate the grid like I have shown in screenshot.